# Embed another database on WordPress page & manipulate the database queries using GET method

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress on my website. I have another, separate database on the website filled with data that I wish to query directly on a WordPress page that I created. I've read through forums and still cannot find a method that works.

So far I have done the following:

Installed a PHP Code Snippets plugin that allows me to embed PHP on WordPress pages. Simple code like `echo "Hello, World!";` works fine when embedded on the page.

The issue seems to be connecting to the database. A sample of my code is below. I will also need to be able to manipulate the database queries using the GET method. Is this possible? I don't want to have to rewrite my database application in order to include it on a WordPress page.

The code below is simply embedded on the WordPress page using the plugin.

```
// Set the database access information as constants:
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'admin');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '1234');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'example_database_name');

// Make the connection:
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ();

// Set the encoding...
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

// Process user selection of surface type
if(isset($_GET['surface_type'])) {
    $form_error = false;

    $surface_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET["surface_type"]));   

    if ($surface_type == "all") {
        // User wants to see all sheets brand
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM sheet_brands ORDER BY brand_name ASC";
    } else {
        // User has selected a certain surface type
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM sheet_brands WHERE surface_type=$surface_type ORDER BY brand_name ASC";
    }

    // User has selected a sheet brand
    if (isset($_GET['brand_name'])) {
        $brand_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET["brand_name"]));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your data base is on localhost, could it be restricted? Also ports?

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham Confirmed. No problem accessing the database if I remove WordPress.

Comment: Ok well the $wpdb object is realy designed to use one database, you can extend this object but it will require alot of work. i woudl refer to the docs and try the hyperdb - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Answer (score -1):

You must manually create a new instance of the wpdb class with right settings for your other database.

From the wpdb Codex page:

> **More Information ** 
>   An instantiated wpdb class can talk to any number of tables, but only to one database at >a time. In
>   the rare case you need to connect to another database, instantiate
>   your own object from the wpdb class with your own database connection
>   information.